# Public kovan test net

Tags: ethereum, metamask, bitcoin-testnet, kovan

How to get Kovan public test net in metamask as I have tried all the recommended sites but did not get it.
These links do not work for me to get it.
https://faucet.kovan.network/
https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this for kovan test network faucet:

1- https://ethdrop.dev/ (unlimited 0.001)

2- https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet (only for 0.001 once in 24 hours)

Comment: https://ethdrop.dev/ (unlimited 0.001)  immediate process to get kovan test network faucet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some Kovan test ETH here https://linkfaucet.protofire.io/kovan

Comment: thanks, but it works sometimes and sometimes not.